# Sieve of Eratosthenes using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, algorithm, primes, stream, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am learning streams and lambdas in Java 8.

I wanted to implement the classic Sieve of Eratosthenes using lambdas and streams. This is my implementation.

```
 /**
 * @author Sanjay
 */
class Sieve {
    /**
     * Implementation of Sieve of eratosthenes algorithm using streams and lambdas 
     * It's much slower than the version with traditional for loops
     * It consumes much memory than the version with traditional for loops
     * It computes all primes upto 100_000_000 in 2 secs (approx) 
     */
    public static List<Integer> sieveOfEratosthenes(int _n) {
        // if _n is empty return an empty list
        if (_n <= 1) return Arrays.asList();
        // create a boolean array each index representing index number itself
        boolean[] prime = new boolean[_n + 1];

        // set all the values in prime as true
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, _n).forEach(x -> prime[x] = true);
        // make all composite numbers false in prime array
        IntStream.rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(_n))
                .filter(x -> prime[x])
                .forEach(x -> unsetFactors(x, prime, _n));
        // create a list containing primes upto _n
        List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<>((_n < 20) ? _n : (_n < 100) ? 30 : _n / 3);
        // add all the indexes that represent true in prime array to primeList
        IntStream.rangeClosed(2, _n).filter(x -> prime[x]).forEach(primeList::add);
        // return prime list
        return primeList;
    }

    /*
     * makes all the factors of x in prime array to false
     * as primes don't have any factors
     * here x is a prime and this makes all factors of x as false
     */
    private static void unsetFactors(int x, boolean[] prime, int _n) {
        IntStream.iterate(x * 2, factor -> factor + x)
                .limit(_n / x - 1)
                .forEach(factor -> prime[factor] = false);
    }
}
```

What is its efficiency compared to normal for-loops?
Are there any imporvements to be made?

Comment: @greybeard Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Implementation

You can invert the values for `prime` and `not prime` to avoid the initial `rangeClosed(0, _n).forEach(x -> prime[x] = true)`. The innermost loop can start at `x*x` instead of `x*2`:

```
// (1)
public static List<Integer> sieveOfEratosthenes(int n) {
    boolean[] notPrime = new boolean[n + 1];

    IntStream.rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(n))
            .filter(x -> !notPrime[x])
            .forEach(x -> {
                IntStream.iterate(x * x, m -> m <= n, m -> m + x)
                        .forEach(y -> notPrime[y] = true);
            });

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.rangeClosed(2, n)
            .filter(x -> !notPrime[x])
            .forEach(x -> list.add(x));
    return list;
}
```

This implementation still feels like a literal translation of the for-loop approach. Streams offer options to improve readability, i.e. the inner loop can be flattened:

```
// (2)
public static List<Integer> sieveOfEratosthenes(int n) {
    boolean[] notPrime = new boolean[n + 1];

    rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(n))
            .filter(x -> !notPrime[x])
            .flatMap(x -> iterate(x * x, m -> m <= n, m -> m + x))
            .forEach(x -> notPrime[x] = true);

    return rangeClosed(2, n)
            .filter(x -> !notPrime[x])
            .boxed().collect(toList());
}
```

#### Stream vs Loop

The main problem I see with a stream based approach is (besides the overhead of the streams), that it is more difficult to optimize compared to a loop approach as the abstraction level is higher. For example converting the implementation to a parallel approach is in my opinion way more complicated with a stream approach.

#### Algorithm improvements (not directly related to the question)

You can use a `BitSet` (or directly a `long`/`int`/`byte` array) to ensure that each entry in the sieve consumes only one bit (instead of currently (likely) 8). You are storing all values from `2` to `n` in the sieve, you can save memory by skipping multiples of `2` (and `3`, `5`, ...) at the cost of some additional calculations to convert between sieve position and value.

For larger values of `n` it might be advantageous to divide the sieving process in smaller steps and use a small array instead of a large array for all values and sieving the complete range at once.

The sieving process can be converted to a parallel implementation with nearly linear speedup as two or more values can be sieved simultaneously (sieving process of each value is independent from other values).

Approx. performance for `n=100_000_000`, included my implementation (which utilizes most of the improvements mentioned above) as reference value:

```
// 1 Thread
Initial            3406676978ns
Version (1)        2487619662ns
Version (2)        2459434320ns
For loop           2158261344ns
Nevay to List      1436579484ns
Nevay to Sieve     1040829243ns
// 8 Threads
Nevay to List       682085628ns
Nevay to Sieve      172952467ns
```